# Validation Rule on Phone Field to allow only Numbers or Blank

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I wanted to write a validation rule for default Phone field.

```
AND( 
    NOT(ISBLANK( Phone )), 
    NOT(ISNUMBER( Phone )) 
)
```

it works fine but allows only 9 digits.
What could be the problem?
When i Deactivate this validation rule, it accepts more than 10 digits or alphabets.
Why is the Number restriction enforced?

Comment: What error are you getting when you add more than 9 digits?

Comment: Validation error which i mentioned in the validation rule

Answer (score 2):

Ten digit numbers are automatically reformatted as '(###) ###-####', which means that ISNUMBER will return false (because it has spaces, parentheses, and a hyphen). Also, when you see the documentation, you'll see it also supports numbers like 2e2 or 123.123, which are both *numbers*, but not *phone numbers*.

So, what you're probably looking for, for a start, is two specific patterns that will match US and other numbers:

```
AND(NOT(REGEX(Phone,'\\d*')), NOT(REGEX(Phone,'\\(\\d{3}\\) \\d{3}-\\d{4}')))
```

You'll want to experiment with REGEX to determine which rule(s) you'd like to follow.

Comment: Thanks

It is accepting < 10 digits and >10 digits.

I figured this is better.

IF(
ISBLANK(Phone) , false , NOT( REGEX( Phone,"(\\D?[0-9]{3}\\D?)[\\s][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"))
)